# Long time user - suspicious activity

Tags: discussion

Spotted this user which has a high number of cast votes on the site, however, seems like IT has not really contributed to the site, except for voting and the occasional edit for gaining rep (i'm assuming that this had been done in order to be able to vote?, however, I have no way of confirming this):
[user13639](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/13639/user13639?tab=profile)

could this be a dupe account?

Comment: I don't see any reason to believe this person is a duplicate.

Comment: Ok - thanks for checking =-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This person seems clearly not a duplicate based on my analysis. >10k helpful flags, dozens of approved edits, and no suspicious vote patterns or IP cross reference.

Comment: 10,138 helpful flags!!! criky!... in contrast @glls only has 1.

Comment: @Robs To be fair to glls, you are looking at his meta flags, not the main site.

Comment: My bad! @gills does have 800 on SFSE, a very respectable amount.

Comment: Just curious how one can have > 10K helpful flags when one has not posted any question or comments?

Comment: You do not need to participate in any other way to raise flags. There is no reputation threshold.